# How to Separate one column data which contains multiple paragraph in to different column means one paragraph per one column in MS-Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I use data option in Excel but it cant help me.
Suppose I have one essay with "X" no of paragraph which is stored in one cell of a excel sheet now I want to separate this one column in to multiple cell with one paragraph in one cell in a row

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your paragraphs don't contain any line breaks of their own, you can use Excel's text to columns wizard to split the text by specifying a line break as your delimiter.

1. Select the column containing the text to be split
2. Start the wizard from `Data` -> `Text to Columns`
3. Delimited
4. Tick `other`. In the text box press `ctrl`-`j` to specify a line break as delimiter.
5. Specify your destination if necessary.